# Listing users prior to linux login prompt

Tags: login

On Arch Linux x64, not using any display manager/desktop env.

Is there any way to list all "real" users (the ones who can login) before the username/password login prompt?

I already know how to get a simple user list with `cat /etc/passwd | grep '/home/' | awk -F: '{ print $1 }' | paste -s -d ',' | sed -e 's/,/, /g'`, all that's missing is to output this command at startup.

I also know of `/etc/issue` but it is not sourced at startup.

Much appreciated if anyone knows a way to output the command (or similar) above before the prompt!

Comment: Your five commands can be replaced by one: `awk -F: -v ORS=', ' '$6 ~ "^/home/" { print $1; }' /etc/passwd`

Comment: What do you mean by "but it is not sourced at startup"?

Comment: @HaukeLaging 1. that command removes the trailing newline which I'd like to keep :/ 2. I meant that if you put commands there they won't be run, they'll just be printed as is, is there a better wording?

Comment: `awk -F: -v ORS='' '$6 ~ "^/home/" { print sep $1; sep=", " }; END { print "\n" }' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit /etc/issue from a service.

Comment: or even call that `awk` statement referenced in the other answer in `/etc/rc.local`.  but I question *why* you'd want to do this...